# I want to add wordpress posts by phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress

I already did that, but when I visit the URL for the new post I added I stocked with "the page doesn't exist", while the title shows at the new posts feed and the title and content show at the archive.

and if I press edit, I saw everything right (title/content)

What is wrong?

I tried add post from wordpress admin panel to compare, two posts are the same.

Comment: What is the state of your post? Has it been published?

Comment: yup , thank you

And i found the error , the URL i put is only numbers , when i add just one letter at first it work